# Lightning-map select marker

Tags: lightning-web-components, google-map, lightning-map

I have a `lightning-map` component in my LWC component.

I hide the list of markers as I do not like what the component has and provide my own.

If user clicks on a marker in the map, I can handle and scroll my list appopriately through `onmarkerselect`.

However, there does not seem to be a way to programmatically select a marker. Setting `selected-marker-value={currentMarkerValue}` has no effected on the map. To be precise, the expectation is that the info window (gmaps term) aka the little bubble pop up should show up.

**Update** This is specifically when map is declared with `list-view="hidden"` attribute

Comment: My initial interpretation was that you have custom implementation of marker list that required a programmatic selection and I posted the answer on those lines. Clearly that's not the expectation and hence, deleted my answer. I've added your comment to this question to make it a bit more precise (hope you don't mind).

Comment: Custom implementation of marker list - this is exactly what i have. I hide their default list since I can’t customise it’s appearance and make my own list. I want just like withtheir list - if user clicks an item, the popup should open

Comment: Short answer: Not possible with the base component.

Comment: Under the hood, lightning-map uses a whole lot of google maps APIs and private lightning base components which facilitate the various functions (including the pop-up info). Default marker list is based on lightning-primitive-coordinate-item (each entry in the list corresponds to one component) and each entry gets a GUID (which will be same as the GUID of corresponding map marker). When you click on an item, a custom event is dispatched (with this GUID in detail attribute) and the maps APIs invoke the event handler to display pop-up.

Comment: The click event that displays the info occurs much earlier in the chain of events and `markerselect` event is the last one in this chain. The sole purpose of `markerselect` event seems to be able to fetch the selected marker value and use it. Since, you can't programmatically hack into the shadow DOM, you can't get the marker GUIDs and invoke the specific click event. The click event in your custom list implementation bypasses all the internal events and hence, no pop-up.

Comment: You can debug and explore all of this from the browser src panel (if interested). Actual details to explain this entirely would be a very long answer which will not provide a solution you are looking for and hence, posting these as comments.

Comment: I have seen all of that code today. In the primitive map js there is actually a handler if event contains selctedMarkerId but map.js never dispatches that which is stupid.

Comment: Which method or function are you referring to from primitive map and map JS files? They might be designed for specific pruposes. If you look into the default implementation  of lightning map, the click event of the list item originates from `primitiveCoordinateItem.js` which inturn invokes the functions on these other JS files.

Comment: If you look at primitive map served here: https://maps.a.forceusercontent.com/lightningmaps/mapsloader?version=226&resource=primitiveMap

there is, for example, `makeMarkerActive` that would be good enough, or inside `handleMessage` there is a ` if (incoming.activeMarkerId) {  this.activeMarkerId = incoming.activeMarkerId; }` which would also be enough. But the map.js (which is the code for LWC portion of lightning-map) never dispatches that `activeMarkerId` when you set `selectedMarkerValue`.

Comment: True and it would be good to have this info for minor customization (in this specific case). All of this boils down to the unavailable GUID of the markers. I bet all of this is just by design to abstracting the actual implementation details. Again, if I were developing a component, I wouldn't expose the GUIDs to the consumer and construct it from functional usage point of view.

Comment: @zaitsman did you ever make any headway with the info window when listview is hidden? I am stuck in a similar situation.

Comment: @Pauline for us it was decided that the ability to customise the list is more valuable than the bubble popping up on the list item click, so we just went with that behaviour. I wish they changed it one day.

Comment: Thanks @zaitsman

Comment: Just an observation: If I set `list-view="visible"` and programmatically set `selected-marker-value` I can see the marker being selected in the list, but as per the OP no popup appears next to the marker. This with the current version of LWC but I suspect it has always done this.